# On/Off status with jQuery

Tags: jquery

There is a plugin to fav & unfav my data? I have an example:

**`id name status`**
`1  jackii on`
`2  derekk off`
`3  carool on`

I want to on/off my data instally without refresh (the same idea used by many webapps. like gmail ...)

Actually I use PHP with $_GET to update the status

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're basically trying to do is to get an ajax call to get the data from your server side and just refresh the page.

there's a few ways to do to this, but since you're asking specifically for PHP, you might want to [learn via this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_intro.asp).

else you can also use [jquery $.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to retrieve the data and update the page.
if you're stuck you can always come back and ask for specific help.